# Android NDK path variable

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to compile a OpenCV sample project. I get an error saying "ndk-build.cmd" not found in PATH. I have added C:\android-ndk-r8d to my PATH under System Variables. I am working in Windows. here is a screenshot of the Problems tab in Eclipse:

[image]

Comment: you have add system variable $NDKROOT?

Answer (score 1):

```
Windows --> preferences --> Android --> NDK --> browser ndk location
```

Comment: I did this. It doesn't fix the problem.